# How to prevent GhostScript from cropping pdf files?

Tags: ghostscript

I'm using this command to create a thumbnail from PDF files:

```
gswin64c -sDEVICE=pngalpha 
         -sPageList=1
         -dTextAlphaBits=4
         -r96
         -o "D:\output.png" 
         "D:\input.pdf"
```

However, it's cropping an inner rectangle from the PDF page (even letting out content).

How can I instruct GhostScript to render an image from the entire space (including all the "blank" space of the page)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ghostscript will, by default, use the MediaBox of the PDF file to set the size of the output, which appears to be what you are asking for. Nothing in your command line will change that.

Its **possible** that what you want is the BleedBox, in which case `-dUseBleedBox` will use that instead of the MediaBox.

However, you haven't supplied the PDF file so I cannot tell what might actually be going on. How do you know the page size is cropped ? What are you comparing against ? Which version of Ghostscript are you using  (clearly you are using Windows) ?

It would be best to post an example PDF file where people can look at it, without that its not really possible to help you.